# Marklogic MLCP: how to get number of records inserted?

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

I am loading data using mlcp. After completion of this process how can i get the number of documents inserted into the db?

Edit: Actually I am initializing this MLCP process from java and i want the record inserted count in the java application. How can i fetch the record inserted count from Java Application

Answer (score 1):

When it runs, mlcp logs `ATTEMPTED_INPUT_RECORD_COUNT` and any errors. You could use that.

If you start with a known count, you could look at the database status in the admin UI.

Now that your documents are in the database, you can also query for them and count them using [`xdmp:estimate`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:estimate). For example it's often a good idea to set an output collection with a timestamp built into it. Or if `maintain-last-modified` is enabled you could use that.

If these ideas don't help, maybe you can clarify the question?

Comment: Thank you mblakele, Actually I initialize the MLCP process from Java layer and I want use this ATTEMPTED_INPUT_RECORD_COUNT value in the java application. Please help me on how to get this count value in Java Application. Thank you in advance

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't see any mlcp API documentation aside from the `com.marklogic.contentpump.SequenceFile*` interfaces. So aren't you using undocumented and unsupported functionality to start mlcp? That's ok with me, but it means you're probably on your own for other functionality. You might peek into the `DocumentMapper` class and its use of `ContentPumpStats` and hadoop counters. But you'd need a `Context` object, and I'm not sure how to get that. Also keep in mind that the code structure could change at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a manual way to get the count, or are you looking for a programmatic way to get the count, where you may have some code that does something with that count?

For the latter, I second mblakele's answer above - collections are easy to abuse, but I think this is a good use case for them, assuming you already have some other documents in your database and thus can't just count all the documents in the database. Use -output_collections to specify a collection, and then use the XDBC server that MLCP uses and issue an xdmp:estimate query to get the count back.

And if it is the latter, I'm interested if you're using some kind of ETL tool to invoke MLCP - e.g. Camel, Spring Integration, or one of the many graphical tools out there. Improving MLCP's integration with these tools is an area of interest of mine - see https://github.com/rjrudin/ml-camel-client for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am with "mblakele". MLCP supports log4j to record all the activities. To setup log4j goto 'conf' directory of MLCP installation directory and change the content of 'log4j.properties' with

```
#Define the root logger with appender file
log = C:/mlcp-Hadoop2-1.2-3/Log
log4j.rootLogger = INFO, FILE

#Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/log.out

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %p %c{2}: %m%n
```

It will create a log file under 'Log' folder where you may get the ingested record count. For example:

[image: MLCP LOG]